# How to get text inside span, and use it into other script

Tags: javascript, dom, html

let say..

```
<span id="Singer">Bieber</span>
```

I know by using DOM I can duplicate 'Bieber' to anywhere..

```
<script>
x=document.getElementById("Singer");document.write("<span>" + x.innerHTML + "</span>");</script>
```

..but id doesn't seems working when I want to insert the DOM script into the script below. Is there any way to put 'Bieber' into the script below?

```
<script language=JavaScript src="http://lyricfind.rotator.hadj7.adjuggler.net/servlet/ajrotator/275968/0/vj?z=lyricfind&dim=35518&click=&kw=<I WANT TO PUT BIEBER HERE>"></script>
```

Comment: I guess it's not available at the moment you want to get it. Could you some more of your code?

Comment: I just want to post 'bieber' and the licensee asking me to put on their ad script along with my bieber post. But the ad script requires me to fill in the Singer/artist name into the ad script everytime. So instead of fill in manually everytime for every post, I think it is clever to assign span id to some text inside the post, so that the 'fill in the blank' inside the ad script get filled automatically. Or is there any other simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is the browser will be firing off the request for the script before it is able to access the span element. It could be done by dynamically inserting the script tag after the span is read:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var x = document.getElementById("Singer");

    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "http://lyricfind.rotator.hadj7.adjuggler.net/servlet/ajrotator/275968/0/vj?z=lyricfind&dim=35518&click=&kw=" + encodeURIComponent(x.innerHTML);
    s.type = "text/javascript";

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);

};
```

This assumes your page has a `<head>` section. If not, you could append to the body instead.